# How to perform feed forward propagation in CNN using Keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to perform feed forward propagation on CNN using Keras. I am trying to train CNN using my own optimizer, which I can't fit in the optimiser file of Keras. My optimiser in gradient free. I don't want any inbuilt to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gradient free'?

Comment: Gradient free means no gradients are calculated. Basically Evolutionary Algorithms(EAs) are considered to be gradient free.

Comment: OK. But how does it relate to convolutional neural networks?

Comment: I think that will be beyond the scope of question. I am open to discussion if you want to discuss personally. Please mail at bdhariyal94@gmail.com.

Comment: With respect to question, I don't want any optimiser to be involved now, I want to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this question. We just have to make model non trainable.

```
import numpy as np
import keras

x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
y = keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)

model = keras.models.Model(x, y)
model.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

x = np.random.random((10, 3))
y = np.random.random((10, 5))
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10)
```